# MySql Query rows that same values in 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table (MyTable) with this;

```
 id   date        value1   value2
    1    2016-09-16    1       null
    2    2016-09-16    null    null
    3    2016-09-16    3       null
    4    2017-01-16    2       null
    5    2017-01-16    null     1
    6    2017-01-16    null     34
    7    2017-01-16    null      3
```

Needing it to return rows that have matching values in value1 and value2
In above I need rows 1, 3, 5, 7 returned.

If possible sorted by date, value2

Comment: matching in value1 and value2?  in your expected results that is not true.

Comment: Sorry , had typo before the word "returned" , fixed. Rows 1 and 5 have matching values in value1 and value2. Rows 3 and 7 have matching values in value1 and value2. need all those rows returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    *
from
    my_table t
where
    t.value1 in
        (select value2 from my_table)
or  
    t.value2 in
        (select value1 from my_table)
order by 
    t.date, t.value2
```

Comment: returns rows 3 and 7, but not 1 and 5..if I have that correct. Wait, double checking, this may be correct.

Comment: Yes that is it, my db did not have 2 sets as my example did. That is quite tricky , I was thinking something like this with = instead of <> might work as well: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72211/matching-two-rows-in-a-single-table-if-two-specific-keys-have-different-values

Answer (score 0):

Different format output with joins:

```
SELECT
   myt.id as 'ID1',
   myt2.id as 'ID2',
   myt.value1 as 'Value1',
   myt2.value2 as 'Value2'
FROM
   MyTable as myt
      INNER JOIN MyTable as myt2
WHERE
   myt.value1 = myt2.value2
```

Yields:

```
ID1       ID2      Value1     Value2
1          5         1          1
3          7         3          3
```

Answer (score -2):

Just add 'Where' clause with 'value1' IS NOT NULL AND 'value2' IS NOT NULL

Comment: that returns row 6, which does not have a match with another row

Comment: Get no results with that. And true row 4 and 6 needs NOT to be returned.